# Cypress-testrail-reporter creating separate test runs for each test

Tags: cypress, testrail

I have managed to get Cypress to report results into TestRail using the cypress-testrail-reporter. However, when I execute a test run (only manually at the minute using `npx cypress run`) the results of each test are logged as separate test runs. They are currently showing like this:
[Screenshot from my test runs page on TestRail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lATaN.png)

I want the results from each time I execute my test suite to appear as 1 run rather than 5 different runs as shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've bumped into the very same issue. So I've started to use Cypress-accumulative-reporter which fixes this issue. 
This reporter is not perfect btw from time to time it does not publish the last spec executed, so I've created an empty spec file to run at the end... not clean workaround but it works.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter

Comment: Hi Simone. Thank you. This is like an early Christmas present. I'll comment back how I get on.

Comment: ??? This just links back to cypress-testrail-reporter